# onscroll table thead fixed and apply tbody td width to thead th jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 740 )
    {
        //$(".fixed-div-attendance").append($header);
        var first=0;
        var length=$('.table thead tr th').length;
            for (var i=0; i<length; i++)
            {
        console.log(i);
                var thWidth=$(".table").find("th:eq("+i+")").width();
                var tdWidth=$(".table").find("td:eq("+i+")").width();
                if (thWidth<tdWidth)
                {
                if (i==0) {
                    $(".table thead").find("th:first").width(tdWidth-50);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".table thead").find("th:eq("+i+")").width(tdWidth);
                }
                }
                else
                {
                $(".table").find("td:eq("+i+")").width(thWidth);
                }
                first=1;
            }
            $('.table').find('thead ').addClass('fixed-div-attendance');
            //code
        }

    else {
        //$('.table thead tr th:first').css('width','auto');
           $('.table').find('thead ').removeClass('fixed-div-attendance');
    }
    });
```

here i used the above code for onscroll fixed thead , 
how can I minimize this code , it will running each time scrolling , anyway to apply flag and then run it only once.

Comment: "how can I minimize this code", what do mean by that ?

Comment: You can remove the listener at the end of the method, I suppose. Or add a flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your for loop only once, then you need a global variable to check whether it's already triggered or not.. It looks like you are in the right path.. Below is my code:

```
var first=0; //put it outside, so it will be a global variable
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 740 )
    {
        //$(".fixed-div-attendance").append($header);
        if(first == 0){
            myLovelyForLoop();
            first = 1;
        }
        $('.table').find('thead ').addClass('fixed-div-attendance');
        //code
    }
    else {
        //$('.table thead tr th:first').css('width','auto');
           $('.table').find('thead ').removeClass('fixed-div-attendance');
    }
});
function myLovelyForLoop() {
    $('.table thead tr th').each(function(i){
        var thWidth=$(this).width();
        var tdWidth=$(".table").find("td:eq("+i+")").width();
        if (thWidth<tdWidth){
            if (i==0){
                $(this).width(tdWidth-50);
            }else{
                $(this).width(tdWidth);
            }
        }else{
            $(".table").find("td:eq("+i+")").width(thWidth);
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: I change the for loop approach into a more compact code, I cannot guarantee it will directly work as I don't know your HTML structure.. That's build from your code..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register a listener that only runs once, you need to remove the listener in the function itself. I'll use jQuery since it's used in your question.

Using your own code as example:

```
$(window).scroll(onWindowScroll);
function onWindowScroll() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 740) {
        //$(".fixed-div-attendance").append($header);
        var first = 0;
        var length = $('.table thead tr th').length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            var thWidth = $(".table").find("th:eq(" + i + ")").width();
            var tdWidth = $(".table").find("td:eq(" + i + ")").width();
            if (thWidth < tdWidth) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    $(".table thead").find("th:first").width(tdWidth - 50);
                } else {
                    $(".table thead").find("th:eq(" + i + ")").width(tdWidth);
                }
            } else {
                $(".table").find("td:eq(" + i + ")").width(thWidth);
            }
            first = 1;
        }
        $('.table').find('thead ').addClass('fixed-div-attendance');
        //code
    } else {
        //$('.table thead tr th:first').css('width','auto');
        $('.table').find('thead ').removeClass('fixed-div-attendance');
    }
    //This is the end of the on scroll function
    $(window).off("scroll", onWindowScroll); 
});
```

The only new parts are the line `$(window).off("scroll", onWindowScroll);`, and I move the callback to its own function.

Basically, the jQuery function `.scroll(function)` takes a function, and binds it to the scroll event of whatever you call it on. In this case, you bound it to `window`. Since the function is bound to the `scroll` event, and has it's own function definition now, you can *unbind* it with the jQuery function `off`. `.off` simply takes the name of an event, and the function bound to it. In this case `"scroll"` and `onWindowScroll`.